# jQuery dataTables - get filtered column values

Tags: filtering, datatables-1.10

I am using a jQuery dataTable and when the user selects a drop down it searches the data table and filters it and redraws the contents based upon the searched data :

```
mtTable.columns().each(function() {
    mtTable.column(22).search(searchVal, true, true).draw();
});
```

Now I am trying to get all of the column values after a search is done, however I cannot find a function to do this. Currently I am using from the api

```
var myTable = $("#tblResults").DataTable();
var resultsArray = myTable.columns(colIndex).data();
```

According to the documentation this will return all of the data from within the column unfiltered.  I cannot find a function to give me an array of the column values for the filtered data only.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can read all about dataTables advanced `selector-modifiers` here -> http://datatables.net/reference/type/selector-modifier

If you want to get filtered rows only :

```js
table.rows( { search:'applied' } ).data().each(function(value, index) {
    console.log(value, index);
});
```

To target a specific column, and get filtered values only (your specific request) - here all filtered values from column #2 :

```js
table.column(2, { search:'applied' } ).data().each(function(value, index) {
    console.log(value, index);
});
```

See demo with both -> **http://jsfiddle.net/q0e1bdcz/**

To create an array over filtered values for a specific column :

```
var array = [];
table.column(2,  { search:'applied' } ).data().each(function(value, index) {
    array.push(value);
});
console.log(array);
```

See demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/q0e1bdcz/1/**

Comment: any option to get querystring serialized filters of all columns?

Answer (score 4):

You can also get unique and sorted data if you have more entries:

```
// Datatable object
var table = $('#example').DataTable();

// Get Unique and Sorted values.  
table.column(3, { search:'applied' } ).data().unique().sort().each(function(value, index) {
    console.log(value, index);
});
```

Ref: http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/DataTables-Jquery-Table-Plugin/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html

Answer (score 0):

Below is the solution which I used to get all values of a particular column:

```js
oTable = $('#myDatatable').DataTable({
 //your code for datatable
 })

oTable.on('search.dt', function () {
   oTable.column(10).nodes().each(function (cell) {
        var val = cell.innerHTML;
                console.log(val);
                                });
                            })
```